# Best database management system for nested sorting?

Tags: python, mysql, nosql, redis, couchdb

I've got a bunch of events that I need to organize first by location, then by time, then any organization of the remaining attributes (duration, cost, description). The problem is that there are millions of events, so when querying, we only need to retrieve a small section and it should come out ordered, preferably by a third index (cost or duration).

Eventually, the application using this database needs to get the data ultra-fast and will be doing thousands of queries. Unfortunately, we're currently bound to a traditional hard drive, so the data needs to be stored in order. It won't be updated very often (a few hundred writes per day, compared to millions of reads per day).

We've tried MySQL, but even with indicies, it takes 200ms to locate the portion of data we need, probably because our hard drive has to do a ton of seeks, even if it knows where all the data is.

We've looked at NoSQL solutions like key-value stores (Redis, CouchDB), but Redis doesn't do nesting and CouchDB doesn't allow 'ordered sets' since it stores in JSON.

What solutions are there that will help us store based on two (or more) indicies? Bonus points if it has a nice interface with Python!

Answer (score 2):

Without a more exact description of the problem I can't help too much, but I've solved a problem like this using KD-Trees, which are like binary trees but in K dimensions. They allow for *really* fast K-nearest neighbor searches (in my case I can query a corpus of ~10 million documents by latitude, longitude, and time in <1 ms.) Their only real downside is that writing to them is annoying - to keep up performance you have to rebalance the tree pretty frequently. If you want to give it a try, check out the [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) module. Assuming you have scipy installed already you'll be up and running in 10 minutes.

If you're looking for more of an off the shelf database solution, I would consider PostGIS; it will let you create a spatial index on 2-4 dimensions. This will be much more reliable and (and more write-friendly) than a roll-your-own KD tree approach, at the expense of a little bit of performance.

EDIT: I'm assuming here that by "location" you mean geolocation (latitude, longitude). If it's a discrete location like "California" then clearly this answer is not helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! Sorry for the lack of clarity - we've got cities as locations, for example, 'Chicago', so the spatial stuff is awesome, but it won't help us a ton.

Any ideas on how to store data organized by multiple things for quick lookup? Like the example above, stored sorted by location, then start time, then cost?